# What is the difference between none of these, none of them and either of these?

Tags: grammar, differences

What is the difference between none of these none of them and either of these? And are they grammatical correct?
  Here is the context. There are two links and both of links are not working for me. And I wanna tell somone this. So which option can I use in above three?

Answer (score 1):

*None* of those *three* options is correct.  Because you are talking about *two* links, it has  to be *neither*.

*Either* means *one or the other.*